# already install stable ruby but still use old version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i already upgrade the stable Ruby , i was want to generate my rails app, by `bundle install` but it was failed, it said `Your Ruby version is 2.3.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.3.7` then i install by `rvm` then i reboot my laptop, but the Ruby version still like this `ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859) [x86_64-darwin17]`

and then i tried to install rvm stable again, and it said like this:
`Already installed ruby-2.3.8`

how to solve this??

Answer (score 0):

just change you ruby version in Gemfile (this file is located in rails root folder):

[image]

Also check if you have .ruby-version file and change there the ruby version also.

Comment: i did by rvm use ruby 2.38 now, i have some error again to bundle install, it said `You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your
Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'. Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using
RVM are available at rvm.io/packages/openssl.`

Comment: try 
rvm get head
rvm reload 
rvm install (you desired version, ex: 2.6.2)
rvm --default use (you desired version, ex: 2.6.2)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Ruby version on your local machine doesn't match the Ruby version on your Gemfile. Fix:

`$ rvm install 2.3.7`

after version is installed select that version:

`$ rvm use 2.3.7`

Check to see that is the correct version:

`ruby -v`